# Do I need to set SPF record for every domain that uses the mail server?

Tags: postfix, email-server, spf

My mail server is running at for example `mail.example.com` and I have set an SPF record for `example.com` using `v=spf1 mx -all`. `example.com` also has its MX record set as well.

Now I have other domains which use the mail server to send emails, but their MX records are set to `mail.example.com`.

Do I need to set each domain a SPF record like `v=spf1 mx -all` or does it only relate to the mail server which is at mail.example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you must set two records.

For example if the two domains `example.com` and `example.org` share the mail server `mx.example.org` you need two TXT records with the same content (as you wrote `v=spf1 mx -all`).

One of them goes to the zone file of `example.com` and the other goes to the zone file of `example.org`.

Afterwards the following two `dig` calls should yield the correspondig  record as output.

For `example.com`:

```
dig example.com txt
...
example.com.     3600   IN   TXT   "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

And for `example.org`:

```
dig example.org txt
...
example.org.     3600   IN   TXT   "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

Comment: Arhh right ok, so just to confirm... Any domain which shares and sends mail from the same server like info@example.com or joe@domain.com will need the same SPF record?

Comment: Right. If you add an `mx` record to the zone file of `example.co.uk` you have to put also the same `txt` record there.

Answer (score 0):

You use `MX` records for receiving mail while SPF is a technology related to sending mail. The SPF record is checked against the address used in the *envelope sender* address (i.e. the `MAIL FROM` command), not against the `HELO` hostname of the mail server.

Therefore, you should have a SPF record for every domain used for sending mail and it should include every IP address that is permitted to send mail for that domail. The `+mx` in the SPF record is just an alias for every hostname the domain has as an `MX` record. The `ip4`/`ip6` [mechanisms](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4) are recommended to be used, instead.